# Использование статических методов в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Обращаюсь к более опытным товарищам. Имеется класс Class1, в нём есть статические методы. Имеются N потоков (больше 1000), которые должны использовать статические методы класса Class1.

Проблема в том, что я любой из этих методов должен выполняться по очереди(как если бы права доступа были разграничены мьютексом). Подскажите как это можно сделать, могу ли я сделать мьютекс приватным членом класса и использовать его? Вопрос "вдогонку", что будет если несколько потоков одновременно "возьмут" статический метод класса?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Никола Кривошея  Если статический метод не должен владеть какими-либо совместно разделяемыми ресурсами, то все потоки могут обращаться к этой функции.

Comment: Ну так и ограничить их мьютексами, что еще остается? только вот 1000 потоков... не многовато ли? :) Будет очень узкое место... Я так понимаю - требование ваше обойти нельзя? в смысле - даже если методы независимы - все равно только поочередное выполнение?

Comment: Да только поочерёдное(((

Comment: Могу я сделать Mutex как приватный член класса и ориентироваться на него?

Comment: Опишите подробней, как именно происходит обработка данных и использование потоков. По идее, число потоков должно быть равно количеству ядер. А данные должны передаваться из потока в поток через потокобезопасную коллекцию (очередь).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: посмотрите [другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588187/227016) ответ, там предложено более изящное решение.

---

Да, конечно, можно сделать мьютекс приватным членом класса. Если несколько потоков одновременно вызовут статический метод нашего класса, то каждый из них попытается захватить мьютекс, у одного это получится, остальные будут ждать пока этот поток выйдет из метода.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class C {
public:
    static void f() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(static_mutex);
        // Критическая секция, например выведем идентификатор нашего потока
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static std::mutex static_mutex;
};

std::mutex C::static_mutex;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back([] { C::f(); });
    for (std::thread &t : threads)
        t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
Заменил `unique_lock` на `lock_guard` и `thread.detach()` на `thread.join()`, как советуют в комментариях.

Comment: Совершенно нет смысла использовать `unique_lock`, лучше использовать `lock_guard`, т.к. он более лекговесный как в плане реализации, так и в плане семантики.

Comment: `detach` объекта потока может привести к тому, что он вообще не успеет выполнится до выхода из `main`.

Answer (score 7):

Проще всего сделать мьютекс локальным статическим объектом:

```
void f() {
    static std::mutex local_mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(local_mutex);
    // ...
}
```

Плюсы:

1. Не нужно плодить переменные класса
2. Применимо для любых функций/статических методов
3. Минимум кода

Минус:

1. До C++11 нет защиты от одновременной инициализации многими потоками. Поэтому желательно первый вызов функции гарантировать без гонки потоков.

Comment: c++11 гарантирует безопасность инициализации локальных статических объектов при многопоточном использовании.

Comment: Локальные статические объекты (как и любые глобальные сущности) привносят очень много WTF/sec в большие проекты

Comment: @gbg, пардон за глупый вопрос, но что значит "привносят очень много WTF/sec"?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл WTF - найдите правильный перевод в гугле. Корректной будет интерпретация "Какого черта здесь происходит?!". Отнесенное к секунде - ироничное сравнение с физической величиной, по смыслу являющейся потоком.

Таким образом WTF/sec - это количество ругани, высказанной вашим коллегой в попытках разобраться, какого черта здесь происходит, в единицу времени.

Comment: @gbg, на ваш взгляд статическая переменная класса в данном конкретном случае более предпочтительное решение, чем статическая переменная внутри метода? Почему?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Это дело со статическими переменными пахнет (точнее, воняет) за километр плохим дизайном. Следующий вопрос - когда этот поганый дизайн выстрелит - например, в продукте компании, в которой я работаю, ВНЕЗАПНО понадобилось сделать вот такое чудовище, завязанное на статические переменные, многоэкземплярным с полностью независимыми экземплярами - а там примерно 250 KLOC. Вот смеху-то было.